# How to fix hibernate warning (HHH000470)?

Tags: java, hibernate, session

Sometimes, i get this warn message:

```
aug 09, 2017 3:40:02 AM org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection setCurrentSession
WARN: HHH000470: An unexpected session is defined for a collection, but the collection is not connected to that session. A persistent collection may only be associated with one session at a time. Overwriting session. Collection : [royaleserver.database.entity.PlayerEntity.homeChests#1757]
```

PlayerEntity:

```
public class PlayerEntity implements Identifiable<Long>, Serializable {
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "player")
    private Set<HomeChestEntity> homeChests = new HashSet<>();  

    public Set<HomeChestEntity> getHomeChests() {
        return homeChests;
    }

    public PlayerEntity setHomeChests(Set<HomeChestEntity> homeChests) {
        this.homeChests = homeChests;
        return this;
    }
}
```

HomeChestEntity:

```
public class HomeChestEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "player_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private PlayerEntity player;
    ...
}
```

And after this warn message, session is closed.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Session/EntityManager is closed
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.checkOpen(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.SharedSessionContractImplementor.checkOpen(SharedSessionContractImplementor.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.checkOpenOrWaitingForAutoClose(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:343)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getPersistenceContext(SessionImpl.java:2275)
    ...
```

What's the problem?

Comment: why did you remove the answer hook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of error is usually happening if you manage a persisted object in two threads,  mix objects collected from two different sessions, or if you add objects to a collection on a transient object and later try to save it (could be a different message, though).

on all cases, it boils down to improper session management.

Your problem is this code:

```
public PlayerEntity setHomeChests(Set<HomeChestEntity> homeChests) {
    this.homeChests = homeChests;
    return this;
}
```

You are possibly replacing the relation (in the `this.homeChests` field) with the transient set given in the properties.

A better solution would be:

```
if(this.homeChests == null) {
    this.homeChests = new HashSet<>(homeChests);
}
else {
    // very simply, you possibly better sync the new elements in...
    this.homeChests.addAll(homeChests);
}
```

This solution has it's issues also, if you cannot guarantee, that the elements are all new. You may run into stale objects as well.

As I said, you need to take care that your session handling covers the all operations on the tree. Do not simply use transient objects in a new session, you need to merge them in or load them again. I suggest you carefully look at questions on stackoverflow about hibernate session handling. Also, the hibernate docs present some best practices on how to manage session or the entity manager with hibernate.

Comment: Hello :)
I found my error on github. Can you explain me how it is called?

[error example here](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/0a2a5c622e3eb30724e80bc8661c0ac55ebfb2be/hibernate-core/src/test/java/org/hibernate/test/collection/multisession/MultipleSessionCollectionWarningTest.java#L70)

Comment: look at the comment: // Now remove the collection from the PersistenceContext without unsetting its session   // This should never be done in practice; it is done here only to test that the ⚠️ this error has no real name. you could call it transient collection in session